# Como faço para compartilhar posts do meu site no facebook?

Tags: facebook, post

Então galera, sei que muita gente tem dificuldade nisso.
Eu configurei belezinha as meta tags do open graph, mas o problema é que eu queria que o botão share compartilhasse o post especifico da url.

Como faço isso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a SDK do facebook.

Basta carregar a SDK:

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

E depois adicionar o botão de share com a sua URL.

```
<!-- Your share button code -->
<div class="fb-share-button" 
  data-href="http://seusite.com/sua-pagina.html" 
  data-layout="button_count">
</div>
```

Documentação oficial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

Answer (score 1):

Você precisar usar a API apontando a url atual da página:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="URL DA SUA PÁGIA ATUAL" data-layout="box_count" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true">
<a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URL DA SUA PAGINA ATUAL COM ENCODE URI%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Compartilhar</a>
</div>
```

Para pegar a URL da  pagina atual com PHP:

```
<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

Para pegar a url da pagina atual com JS:

```
<script>var urlAtual = window.location.href; </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A melhor alternativa, e a mais funcional, é **remover** o data-href das propriedades do botão share, versão HTML5, em div .
Lembrando que deve ter o SDK implementado, e também recomenda-se o  open graph completo. Mas se tiver META TITLE, já rola o share ...
Porém:  Ao invés do plugin Share, atualmente costuma-se implementar o botão Curtir (ou Recomendar) juntamente com o plugin Compartilhar, que oferece mais opções para o usuário .

Removeu o data-href .. Pronto, vai compartilhar o post da URL que você está !
Dentro desta mesma página voce pode ter elementos de plugin compartilhar, com o data-href apontando para outros URLs, caso queira compartilhar terceiros URLs, estando dentro de uma URL principal, por exemplo .

Tenho utilizado isso há anos, e é a melhor alternativa para esse seu caso .